# UISplitViewController inside UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to put a UISplitViewController inside of a UITabBarController. Unfortunately, this is not supported by Apple, as the UISplitViewController has to be the root view. I can get the SplitView in the TabBarController, but then none of the Bar buttons show. The "Master" button which slides out the MasterViewController that does not appear so I can not use the application in portrait mode.

Has anyone found a solution to this? Perhaps a method call on a custom BarButton to slide out the MasterViewController?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have also been having this issue (although I only have an issue on iOS 7 on iPhones; iOS 8 iPhone/iPad and iOS 7 iPads work fine). If you've not come up with a solution I'll start a bounty for this question? Quick sidenote: Apple appear to have done this in the Game Center app's "Friends" tab

Comment: A late response, but maybe still helpful. See this sample code how to embed a `UISplitViewController` inside of a`UITabBarController` https://github.com/daveanderson/TabsAndSplits